# CQL: Bad Request: Missing CLUSTERING ORDER for column

Tags: cassandra, cql3

What is the problem with this CQL query

```
cqlsh> create table citybizz.notifications(
   ...      userId varchar,
   ...      notifId UUID,
   ...      notification varchar,
   ...      time bigint,read boolean,
   ...      primary key (userId, notifId,time)
   ... ) with clustering order by (time desc);
```

It throws `Bad Request: Missing CLUSTERING ORDER for column notifid`. I am using cassandra 1.2.2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the order for notifId too:

```
create table citybizz.notifications(
    userId varchar,
    notifId UUID,
    notification varchar,
    time bigint,read boolean,
    primary key (userId, notifId,time)
) with clustering order by (notifId asc, time desc);
```

Cassandra doesn't assume default ordering (asc) for the other clustering keys so you need to specify it.